# How can I undo a key remapping?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

A few days ago I was exploring options to remap my CapsLock key to control, and I found a little script online which accomplished this. I ran it, restarted my machine, and everything worked great.

I wanted some more flexibility so today I came across [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Unfortunately, whatever change the previous script made is stomping on my AHK scripts.

I am having a hard time finding the first script I ran that remapped my CapsLock key. It required a restart, so I assume it changed my registry, though there isn't an entry where I would expect (KeyboardLayout).

Any ideas on how I could go about finding this change + undoing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it again. I had come across [Ctrl2cap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897578.aspx), a little utility program that altered the registry in a way that SharpKeys wasn't identifying.

I downloaded the utility again, and used `ctrl2cap /uninstall`, which took care of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Download [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com) and run it. It will show you your current key remaps. Delete what you want, apply and reboot.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't show that there are any bindings. perhaps the script didn't change my registry - what else could it be?

Comment: AFAIK Windows doesn't provide any other mechanism for key remapping. Without having a look at the .REG you merged into your registry it's really hard to say what it might have done.

Comment: SharpKeys should pick up any .REG files that have been merged in?

Comment: Yes, it should pick up any key remaps made using Windows' own [Scancode Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx) mechanism.